# Problem with scanning my C:\ Drive via system.io

Tags: c#, sql, directory

Hello so for school i have to write a script where it scans a whole computer/server and it will put the folders in a database(as a path string).

For some reason tho it never fully scans the c:\ drive. If i had a folder structure like for example:

```
c:
   Folder1
    Subfolder1
    Subfolder2
   Folder2
    Subfolder1
    Subfolder2
```

Than it would read the c:\ drive, it would also read folder 1 and 2 but it won't read annything beyond folder 1 & 2.

I use system.io for c#, its a .net Framework

things i have already tried:
running as administrator

is there annyone who could help me with this problem?

```
using Scan.Properties;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace Scan
{
    class fnscan
    {
        public class global
        {
            public static int typeID;
            public static string getextention;
            public static string extention;
            public List<DriveInfo> Drive;
            public static int scanid;

            public global()
            {
                Drive = new List<DriveInfo>();
            }

            public void AppendToDrive(DriveInfo e)
            {
                Drive.Add(e);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            if (Settings.Default.set_con.Length < 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("U heeft geen verbinding met de databank");
            }


            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Settings.Default.set_con);
            SqlCommand cmdinsert = con.CreateCommand();
            SqlCommand cmdinsertdirectory = con.CreateCommand();
            SqlCommand getmasterid = con.CreateCommand();
            SqlCommand insertscan = con.CreateCommand();
            con.Open();

            try
            {
                insertscan.CommandText = "Insert into dbo.tblScan(fldScanDate,fldCreationData,fldUpdateDate,fldDescription) Values('" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "','" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "','" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "','Automatic scan.')";
                insertscan.Connection = con;
                insertscan.ExecuteNonQuery();


                string getscan = "SELECT TOP 1 fldScanID FROM dbo.tblScan ORDER BY fldScanID DESC";
                SqlCommand cmdscanid = new SqlCommand(getscan, con);

                SqlDataReader readerscanid = cmdscanid.ExecuteReader();

                while (readerscanid.Read())
                {
                    global.scanid = readerscanid.GetInt32(0);
                }
                readerscanid.Close();
            }
            catch (SqlException bruh)
            {
                Console.Write(bruh);
            }

            global D = new global();


            foreach (var drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
            {
                D.AppendToDrive(drive);

                try
                {
                    var di = new DriveInfo(drive.ToString());

                    global.extention = "Drive";
                    var freespace = di.AvailableFreeSpace;
                    var totalspace = di.TotalSize;
                    var size = totalspace - freespace;


                    string type = "Drive";
                    //--------------------------------------//
                    //File extentions vinden en toevoegen als die nog niet bestaat//
                    string gettypeid = "SELECT fldtypeid FROM dbo.tbltype WHERE fldExtention = '" + type + "'";
                    SqlCommand cmdtypeid = new SqlCommand(gettypeid, con);
                    //

                    string getextention = "SELECT fldextention FROM dbo.tbltype WHERE fldExtention = '" + type + "'";
                    SqlCommand cmdextention = new SqlCommand(getextention, con);
                    //

                    SqlDataReader readertypeid = cmdtypeid.ExecuteReader();

                    while (readertypeid.Read())
                    {
                        global.typeID = readertypeid.GetInt32(0);
                    }

                    readertypeid.Close();


                    SqlDataReader readerextention = cmdextention.ExecuteReader();
                    while (readerextention.Read())
                    {
                        global.getextention = readerextention.GetString(0);
                    }
                    string extention = "Drive";
                    readerextention.Close();
                    if (global.extention != extention)
                    {

                        SqlCommand inserttype = con.CreateCommand();
                        inserttype.CommandText = "Insert into dbo.tblType(fldType,fldExtention,fldCreationData,fldupdatedate) values('Nog veranderen','" + extention + "','" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "','" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "')";
                        inserttype.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    //--------------------------------------//


                    Console.WriteLine("---------------------\n" + "Path: " + drive + " ,\n" + "Groote: " + size + " ,\nFile type: " + global.extention + ", This TypeID: " + global.typeID + ",\nReason for this scan: Automatic scan \n---------------------");

                    cmdinsertdirectory.CommandText = "Insert into dbo.tblLocation(fldLocation,fldCurrentSize,fldDescription,fldTypeID,fldAvailableSpace,fldScanID) Values('" + drive + "','" + size + "','Automatic scan','" + global.typeID + "','" + freespace + "','" + global.scanid + "')";
                    cmdinsertdirectory.Connection = con;
                    cmdinsertdirectory.ExecuteNonQuery();



                }
                catch (Exception err)
                {
                }
            }


            var currentDir = "";
            int retMId = 0;


            var fn = new functions();


            for (int i = 0; i < D.Drive.Count; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (var entry in Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(D.Drive[i].ToString(), "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                    {

                        try
                        {

                            var fi = new FileInfo(entry);
                            if (fi.Directory.ToString() != currentDir)
                            {
                                // check op folder niveau

                                currentDir = fi.Directory.ToString();
                                retMId = fn.getLocationID(currentDir);
                            }


                            //uitgang van file (.txt, .png, ...)
                            global.extention = fi.Extension;





                            //Groote van files
                            var size = fi.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Directory)
                        ? Directory.EnumerateFiles(fi.FullName, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                        .Sum(path => new FileInfo(path).Length)
                        : fi.Length;




                            //creationdate
                            DateTime creationTime = fi.CreationTime;



                            //updatedate
                            DateTime updatetime = fi.LastWriteTime;






                            //--------------------------------------//
                            //File extentions vinden en toevoegen als die nog niet bestaat//
                            con.Open();
                            //
                            string gettypeid = "SELECT fldtypeid FROM dbo.tbltype WHERE fldExtention = '" + fi.Extension.ToString() + "'";
                            SqlCommand cmdtypeid = new SqlCommand(gettypeid, con);
                            //

                            string getextention = "SELECT fldextention FROM dbo.tbltype WHERE fldExtention = '" + fi.Extension.ToString() + "'";
                            SqlCommand cmdextention = new SqlCommand(getextention, con);
                            //

                            SqlDataReader readertypeid = cmdtypeid.ExecuteReader();

                            while (readertypeid.Read())
                            {
                                global.typeID = readertypeid.GetInt32(0);
                            }

                            readertypeid.Close();
                            //


                            SqlDataReader readerextention = cmdextention.ExecuteReader();
                            while (readerextention.Read())
                            {
                                global.getextention = readerextention.GetString(0);
                            }

                            readerextention.Close();
                            if (global.extention != global.getextention)
                            {

                                SqlCommand inserttype = con.CreateCommand();
                                inserttype.CommandText = "Insert into dbo.tblType(fldType,fldExtention,fldCreationData,fldupdatedate) values('Nog veranderen','" + fi.Extension.ToString() + "','" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "','" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "')";
                                inserttype.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                            //
                            //--------------------------------------//






                            Console.WriteLine("---------------------\n" + "Path: " + entry + " ,\n" + "CreationTime: " + creationTime + ", " + "UpdateTime: " + updatetime + ",\n" + "Groote: " + size + " ,\nFile type: " + global.extention + ", This TypeID: " + global.typeID + ",\nReason for this scan: Automatic scan\n---------------------");
                            cmdinsert.CommandText = "Insert into dbo.tblLocation(fldLocation,fldCurrentSize,fldcreationdata,fldUpdateDate,fldDescription,fldmasterlocationid,fldTypeID,fldScanID) Values('" + entry + "','" + size + "' , '" + creationTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "' , '" + updatetime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "' , 'Automatic scan' , '" + retMId + "', '" + global.typeID + "','" + global.scanid + "')";
                            cmdinsert.Connection = con;
                            cmdinsert.ExecuteNonQuery();




                        }
                        catch (Exception err)
                        {
                        }



                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception error)
                {

                }
            }
            

            Console.WriteLine("scan geslaagd!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: please use ***parameterised queries*** - building SQL queries by concatenation etc. is a recipe for disaster. not only is it a source for many hard to debug syntax errors, it's also a wide, open gate for ***[SQL Injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/)***.

Comment: also: you are catching exceptions without doing anything with them - in effect swallowing them. ***do not do that***, so the program can tell you what went wrong. then you'll know what to fix.

Comment: I know about the exceptions but they are their just to ignore some files getting scanned and blocking the program but when i showed the errors it didn't show the reason why the c:\ drive did not fully get scanned. It is also only that drive since on my main device i have multiple drives and they all get scanned there except for the C one

Comment: Problem is that once `EnumerateFileSystemEntries()` throws an exception, it'll _stop enumerating file system entries_ - so you might want to go ahead and inspect the exception(s) in the outer `try/catch`

Comment: ok i will, thanks!

Comment: So the error i get is that access to a file gets denied, is it possible that because the program retrys to scan it that it just stops eventually? because i am not getting anny sign of `EnumerateFileSystemEntries()` it is the recycling bin that is causing trouble.

Comment: @RobinHoet There are several files in C drive like "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository" in windows 10. This path has only system rights so no one can access it.

Comment: is there perhaps a way i can ditch those files and just "skip" them other than try catch? because try catch skips most of them and just goes on but i seem to notice that it doesn't scan the whole drive now